What happened to Slic3r?
Looks like it's been 2 years since Slic3r's last github commit, 5 years since the last blog post, and 6 years since the last release.  It seems fairly safe to suppose the project now sleeps the long sleep.  Do we know if anything specific happened, or do we just assume the developer got burned out?  It's a shame, because AFAIK Slic3r was the main open source slicing option.  (Correct me if I'm wrong.)  Are there any active forks?  Other projects now favored?  Rumors of a miraculous resumption of development?

Prusa took over development with the PrusaSlicer fork / rewrite.
They got rid of the Perl parts in Slic3r and added new features.
Then again, based on PrusaSlicer, other slicers emerged:

SuperSlicer, directly based on PrusaSlicer releases, adds new features and bugfixes (like the extrusion width being based on the nozzle instead of layer height);
BambuStudio, a fork and redesign focused on BambuLab printers
OrcaSlicer, a fork of BambuStudio

With all those high-quality forks, development on the original seems to have faded.
